# JDBC MySql driver returns wrong value after working for a long time

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a MySQL db and I have an issue with two tables named `product` and `product_older`. They have same structure and product table's rows copied into product_older for once in a day. Here is their structure:

```
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| price                 | decimal(18,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| price_older           | decimal(18,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I have problem with only `price_older` field. My program updates values of product table for over 3 million data. `price_older` field takes it value from `price` column of `product_older` every time. 
Here is the method which I take price_older:

```
private double getOlderPrice(int id) {
    double price_older = 0.0d;
    try {
        String query = tools.getQuery("select price from product_older where id=?")
            .replace("?", String.valueOf(id));            
        com.mysql.jdbc.Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, username, password);
        preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            price_older = resultSet.getDouble(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ..... // error log
    } finally {
       .... //close the prepared statement
    }
    return price_older;
}
```

And I use that `price_older` value to create `PriceList` object for every product then I used that list to update product table. Here is my update code:
(Same `connection` object used in here with the `getOlderPrice` method.)

```
private void dbUpdate() throws SQLException {

    String query = "update product set price=?, price_older=? where id=?";

    try (com.mysql.jdbc.Statement statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement updateStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query)) {

        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        int batchIndex = 0;

        for (UpdatePrice price : priceList) {

            if (price.getPrice() == null) {
                updateStatement.setNull(1, Types.DECIMAL);
            } else {
                updateStatement.setDouble(1, price.getPrice());
            }
            updateStatement.setDouble(2, price.getOlderPrice());
            updateStatement.setInt(3, price.getID());

            updateStatement.addBatch();

            batchIndex++;
            if (batchIndex % limitedBatchSize == 0) {
                updateStatement.executeBatch();
                connection.commit();
            }
        }

        updateStatement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);

        priceList.clear();
    }
}
```

Here is the problem; It works fine for most of the time but about once every ~30 days it updates older_price with the wrong value and that wrong value is usually belong to another product in the db and when it updates the column with the wrong value there is no error in the log because it appears OK.

And my connection's rewriteBatchedStatements is set to true.

How could that be? If there is a bug, why it works fine most of the time and how there is no problem with the `price` column? If there is not why it updates a value in the wrong place?

I have been searched for over a week now but there is no result and also I can not reproduce the bug and it makes less possible to be sure where is the problem actually.

Comment: concurrent request to this method?

Comment: I do not think so. Because in the first method, ID comes in a json into another method and that method gets the id then calls getOlderPrice() method with the id. And there is no concurrent request for the other method either.

Comment: How many instances of this process you have? Is it a single process that is called by some scheduler? Or is it called per user request?

Comment: This java program is always running in a server(7/24) and it gets the data as json from a rabbit message queue and it receives jsons at the same time every day.